# Qt crashes/doesn't appear when i use Qthread::sleep to update progress bar

Tags: c++, qt

I am kinda new to QT so i am wondering why is this invalid:

I have a progress bar and i want to update it by using a class that inherits `QThread`.

```
void mt::run(QProgressBar * asd){

for(int i = 0;i<100;i++){
    asd->setValue(i);
    QThread::sleep(100);
}

}
```

mt is a class that inherits `QThread`. `run` is overloaded with a `QProgressBar` argument. My main UI thread will send it's progressbar like this `m.run(ui->progressBar);`. If i will remove the `QThread::sleep(100);` then it will work fine but i won't be able to see the increment because the thread will be done so fast. But if i will put a little delay, my screen won't appear at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access and update GUI elements from the main thread only.

If you want to prepare some data inside a custom thread, you should use the signals/slots mechanism to send that data to your widgets.

Here's a basic example:

```
class MyThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyThread(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:
    void valueChanged(int value);

protected:
    void run();
}

void MyThread::run()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        emit valueChanged(i);
        QThread::sleep(100);
    }
}

MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent) : 
    QWidget(parent)
{
    QHbovLayout *layout = new QHbovLayout(this);
    QProgressBar *pb = new QProgressBar;
    layout->addWidget(pb);

    MyThread *t = new MyThread(this);
    connect(t, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), pb, SLOT(setValue(int)));

    t->start();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    // we are in the main thread here, so we can create a widget
    MyWidget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Yes, along with all other widgets you have there. All UI components (no matter which widget they belong to) run in the main thread. My advice is to really look into the slots and signals paradigm of Qt (@hank has described pretty well what you have to do) because this is the proper way to interact between widgets. Also if you know some Python you might want to try PyQt, where things are still Qt but simplified a lot and you can learn faster (personal opinion of course).

Comment: You can create widgets inside the main thread only. I've updated my answer.

Comment: +hank what's the definition of valuechanged?

Comment: @CarloBrew It's just a signal name.

Answer (score 2):

```
QThread::sleep(100);
```

You are telling it to sleep for a 100 seconds - that's quite a long time.  Perhaps you meant [`QThread::msleep(100)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#msleep)?